# How to display search results from onclick function on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like some help in display search results on page. The script below displays the results in an array.

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function genericVideo_Handler(data)
    {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            var row = obj[i];
            alert(row.video_description);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject, Topic, Keyword" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id ="searchSub" onClick="getVideosByKeywords(document.getElementById('srch-term').value, genericVideo_Handler)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**php**

```
public function getVideosByKeywords($keywords)
{
    $sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM portal_videos WHERE MATCH(video_objectives,     video_keywords, video_description) AGAINST ("%s")', $keywords);

    $resultSet = $this->dataConnection->query($sql);

    if($resultSet === false) {
        trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $this->dataConnection->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    } else {
        $rows_returned = $resultSet->num_rows;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Displaying something on a page is the basic idea of html... Describe in detail how you want it to look, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: where is the definition of `getVideosByKeywords()`? Have you defined it?

Comment: i edited to include the definition of getVideosByKeywords();

Comment: I'd like to display on the page in a table with each row as array of video_description instead of an alert box

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share some of the basic information about the events in jQuery.

You can search for the keyword on click event as

```
$('element').event(fucntion () {
  // function to execute..
})
```

Now, since you are new to jQuery I would try to clarify the job.

```
$('button').click(function () { // on a click on botton
  $('.searchresults').show(); // show the div with the search results
})
```

What this would be is something like this:

```
<div class="searchresults">
  Search Results
    First result
    Second result
    Third result
</div>
<button>Show Results</button>
```

in the CSS

```
.searchresults {
  display: none;
}
```

Now, you can change the code and execute it. This time the element won't be visible initially and a button will be present once you click on it, you will get the result shown.

You can handle the result on the PHP (server-side) on your own, and get the response. Then populate the element (searchresults) and show it once the button is clicked.

For more information:

http://api.jquery.com/click/ (jQuery Click)

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ (jQuery selectors)